# Как написать тест кейсы по уже готовому продукту?

Tags: тестирование

В тестовом задании на позицию Junior QA, кроме всего прочего дали задание написать тест кейсы по уже готовому продукту. Подскажите ,пожалуйста, как поступить более правильно. Искать именно ошибки, или можно не находить уже существующие баги, а придумать их самому? 
Ведь насколько я понимаю смысл этого не найти ошибки, а увидеть мое понимаени?

Comment: Лучше уточнить у ребят которые давали вам это задание, что они хотят и как будет лучше. А если боитесь спрашивать, можно найти на оф.сайтах нестабильный релиз какого-либо линукса, установить на vbox и вперед! Можно начать с графики например. Но лучше же конечно уточнить ..

Comment: Изначально проверяйте функциональные требования, а не сразу ищите ошибки и подвохи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу предположить на основании тех кейсов, которые мы давали своим тестрировщикам. (Мы правда для этого писали специальное приложение, с багами, и отдавали тестерам, но то так).
Цель тестировщика не найти баги (как ни странно это не звучит), а протестировать функционал. Соответсвенно тест кейс не обязательно должен находить баг (особенно если его нет), он должен проверять что все приложение работает так, как оно задумывается.
Банальный вариант на авторизацию:

- Открыть авторизацию
- Вбить имя
- Вбить цифру
- Вбить имя из 70 тысяч символов
- Вбить "ничего"

И так далее.. Багов тут может и не быть (и не должно быть), но ключевое это идея что функционал работает.